# MongoDB .remove() matching multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collection called messageLogs, and I am able to delete those documents which contain an empty array in messageLog field via the following:

```
messageLogs.remove({ 
    messageLog: { 
      $eq: {} 
    } 
  });
```

My problem is that I need to do an AND condition to only remove those documents which also match chatId

```
chatId: {
  $eq: chatId
}
```

How do I perform this kind of operation with .remove()?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/ there you go

Comment: thanks man, no idea how I missed that.. it's late